# Docs for Symfony2 namespace

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, namespaces, doctrine

While following Symfony2 tutorial from official website I used this namespace

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
```

I was looking for docs of this namespace on http://api.symfony.com/2.4/index.html
but did not find this namespace among other listed ones. So now guessing that its not part of `Symfony2` so has not been listed there.

Is my guess true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's true.

The first element of a namespace is called the vendor name. It's the name of the package of that namespace. This namespace starts with `Doctrine`, it's from the Doctrine ORM.

Everything created by Symfony starts with `Symfony`.